# How to make id field auto_increment using mysql in command line?

Tags: mysql

I have a table which is given below and I need to its primary key as **auto_increment** and insert the value. I'm explaining my table structure below.

> db_city:

```
city_id   city_name    date
```

I created the table using the below command.

```
CREATE TABLE spesh (city_id INT(11),city_name VARCHAR(200),date DATETIME);
```

But here I forget to add auto_increment. The above are the three fields of `db_city` table. Here I need to make city_id as auto_increment and its data type is `int(11)` now. I also need to insert the value using command line.

Please help me.

Comment: Try this...alter table animals change city_id city_id int(11) auto_increment primary key;

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this:

```
CREATE TABLE animals (
     id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     name CHAR(30) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Or to add it using alter like:

```
ALTER TABLE animals CHANGE id id INT(11)AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;
```

**NOTE:** Auto Increment automatically fill its value if some records present in the table.

Comment: @ Mayank Pandeyz : Its showing sql syntax error near INT(10)AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY;

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE db_city MODIFY COLUMN city_id INT auto_increment
```

Comment: here table name is db_city.